# Introducing blank lines

Tags: line-breaking

I want to introduce a blank line in my document.  But have seen that `\\` and `\newline` do not always make a blank line.  Only `\hfill \break` seems to work consistently.  Any advice on this would be considered valuable.

Comment: you should almost never have `\\ ` and never have `\break` in a document. If you want a style with vertical space between paragraphs choose a suitable class, or use `\usepackge{parskip}`

Comment: You are asking loads of basic questions, perhaps step back and work through a tutorial such as https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-11

Comment: Use something like `\bigskip` between blank lines in the input. ***Never*** use ``\\`` nor `\hfill\break` for the purpose.

Comment: I do use indents for paragraphs without blank lines between them.  But at times I would need a blank line between a paragraph and the next.  Would it be better to make a command in my style file so users would not put ` \\ ` or ` \break `.  Or perhaps `\bigskip` as suggested.  Although my questions seem basic, I find that tutorials seldom provide wisdom on how best to handle things.  One one gets commands to copy without information on latex design details.

Comment: no working through the learnlatex tutorial (mostly written by regulars here) would save you (and us) a lot of time rather than just asking out of context questions like this one. which can only have vague partial answers like "don't do that" or "use `\bigskp`"

Comment: You are right.  One finds so much material showing "\\" and "\break", that I just used them before.  Meaning that even "don't do that" or "use \bigskip" has been instructive.  Again this is not a criticism on what you are saying.

Comment: @egreg Would `\vspace{5mm}` also be acceptable?

Comment: @konmi No: you can set the amount of vertical spacing used by `\bigskip` once and for all, setting the value to the register `\bigskipamount`; if you use `\vspace{5mm}` and then decide it's not really good, you have to change all of them manually. Moreover `\bigskip` usually has flexible space, which helps pagination.

Comment: Would this be good to change the value of  `\bigskipamount`?  `\newcommand{\lex-bgv}[1]{\setlength{\bigskipamount #1 }}`

Comment: why would you introduce a command? but if you do it should of course be `\setlength\bigskipamount{#1}` not `\setlength{\bigskipamount #1 }`

Comment: I am more interested in working on style files than producing documents right now.  Thusly, I am focusing on expanding my experience in setting things up, whatever they may be.

Comment: Have also seen `\setlength{\parindent}{#1}`.  Would this be wrong?  If not, can it be applied to `\bigskipamount` as well.  In summary, doing `\setlength{\bigskipamount}{#1}`.